# Classname.class.getClassLoader equivalent in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am creating a map application in Xamarin.android.

I am trying to initialize an class object from the `Parcel(IParceable)`.

I have the following code which I need to know the C# equivalent of:-

```
private Place(Parcel in){
        this.mLat = in.readString();
        this.mLng = in.readString();
        this.mPlaceName = in.readString();
        this.mVicinity = in.readString();
        this.mPhotos = (Photo[])in.readParcelableArray(Photo.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

Any idea how this can be achieved??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var photos = i.ReadParcelableArray(new Photo().Class.ClassLoader).Cast<Photo>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarin equivalent of `ClassName.class.getClassLoader()` is `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ClassName)).ClassLoader`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that would be:

```
var loader = context.ClassLoader;
var photoClass = loader.LoadClass("Your.Namespace.Photo");
this.mPhotos = (Photo[])in.readParcelableArray(photoClass);
```

But to be hones I have never used `Parcel` before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error saying cannot implicitly convert from Java.Lang.Class to Java.Lang.CLassLoader on the third line

Comment: True. It wants a ClassLoader object. Sorry, I don't know then.